# Print everything before relevant symbol and keep 1 character after relevant symbol

Tags: regex, linux, awk, sed

I'm trying to find a one-liner to print every before relevant symbol and keep just 1 character after relevant symbol:

Input:

```
thisis#atest
thisisjust#anothertest
just#testing
```

Desired output:

```
thisis#a
thisjust#a
just#t
```

`awk -F"#" '{print $1 "#" }'` will almost give me what I want but I need to find a way to print the second character as well. Any ideas?

Comment: What if there is no `#`? What if there's a `#` with no char after it? What if there's 2 `#`s on one line? etc., etc. If you want a robust solution then post sample input/output that covers all your use cases not just the one, most trivial, best-case scenario..

Answer (score 1):

You can substitute what's after the first character after `#` with nothing with sed:

```
sed 's/\(#.\).*/\1/'
```

Comment: A small variation  `sed -r 's/(#.).*/\1/' file` (less escaping)

Answer (score 0):

You could use grep:

```
$ grep -o '[^#]*#.' infile
thisis#a
thisisjust#a
just#t
```

This matches a sequence of characters other than `#`, followed by `#` and any character. The `-o` option retains only the match itself.

Answer (score 0):

With the special `RT` variable in GNU's awk, you can do:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="#.|\n"}RT!="\n"{print $0 RT}'
```

Answer (score 0):

***1st Solution:*** Could you please try following.

```
awk 'match($0,/[^#]*#./){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}'  Input_file
```

Above will print lines as per your ask which have `#` in them and leave lines which does not have it, in case you want to completely print those lines use following then.

```
awk 'match($0,/[^#]*#./){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH);next} 1'  Input_file
```

***2nd solution:***

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="#"} {print $1,substr($2,1,1)}'  Input_file
```

Comment: @bobylapointe, Could you please check these solutions and let me know if they were helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Get the index of the '#', then pull out the substring.

```
$ awk '{print substr($0,1,index($0,"#")+1);}' in.txt 
thisis#a
thisisjust#a
just#t
```

Answer (score 0):

Some small variation of Ravindes 2nd example

```
awk -F# '{print $1"#"substr($2,1,1)}' file
awk -F# '{print $1FS substr($2,1,1)}' file
```

Another `grep` variation (shortest posted so far):

```
grep -oP '.+?#.' file
```

- `o` print only matching
- `P` Perl regex (due to `+?`)
- `.` any character
- `+` and more
- `?` but stop with:
- `#`
- `.` pluss one more character

If we do not add `?`. This line `test#one#two` becomes `test#one#t` instead of `test#o` do to the greedy `+`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use awk, the cleanest way to do this with is using `index` which finds the position of a character:

```
awk 'n=index($0,'#') { print substr($0,1,n+1) }' file
```

There are, however, shorter and more dedicated tools for this. See the other answers.